# In lwc lightning-combobox not able to select a value when binded dynamically, If i bind it with hardcoded values then i am able to select it

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, lightning-combobox

I am using below code to populate a combobox with dynamic value. But i am not able to select any value and it just gets back to blank value with placeholder text.

HTML Code

[image]

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Demo Screen"  class="slds--around_medium">   
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
            <lightning-combobox 
                    name="Month"
                    label="Month"
                    value={value}
                    placeholder="Select Month"
                    options={MonthArr} 
                    onchange={handleMonthChange}>
                </lightning-combobox>
        </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS Code

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable no-alert */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

import { LightningElement,api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class PaymentScreen extends LightningElement {

    @track MonthArr=[];
    @track isFirstLoad = true;


    connectedCallback() {
        if(this.isFirstLoad)
        {
            console.log('in con call back');
            for(var num = 1;num<=12;num++){
                const option = {
                    label: num,
                    value: num
                };
                this.MonthArr = [ ...this.MonthArr, option ];
            }

       }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your handleMonthChange method?

Comment: that is blank...no code in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` needs to be a string for the comparison to match and the combobox to work.

---

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    value;
    months;
    connectedCallback() {
        this.months = [...Array(12).keys()]
        .map(k=>({label: `${k+1}`, value: `${k+1}`}));
    }
    handleMonthChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```

---

Notice the use of `${k+1}` to construct a string value from the numeric input. This ensures that the value will match correctly.

Here's the [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/sRA7SHgpl/1/edit) for this change.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. That solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need `handleMonthChange` method. Please update your JS as follows

```
import { LightningElement,api, track } from 'lwc';
export default class PaymentScreen extends LightningElement {
 value = 1;
@track MonthArr=[];
@track isFirstLoad = true;
connectedCallback() {
    if(this.isFirstLoad)
    {
        console.log('in con call back');
        for(var num = 1;num<=12;num++){
            const option = {
                label: num,
                value: num
            };
            this.MonthArr = [ ...this.MonthArr, option ];
        }
   }
}
handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```

[Playground Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/N77xbh_MS/1/edit).

Comment: But it still does not work Manish. In the playground link which you shared , now default value is 1, but if you try to change it to any other value then instead of showing that value it is showing the placeholder text "select progress". I need that when user selects a value from drop down then it gets selected